# How could a Windows service get its handle?

Tags: windows, service

A service, which I'm developing, needs to call ChangeServiceConfig2 to change its configuration parameters. The function requires a service handle. So, to get its handle, the service calls OpenSCManager, which succeeded, and later OpenService. In the parameter lpServiceName of OpenService function I specify the name of the service but I got "Access denied". I changed the access rights in the manifest file to "requireAdministrator" but still got the error.
In general, how could a Windows service get its handle?

Comment: OpenService() is the correct call, but the service will have to be running with administrator privilege in order to reconfigure itself.  What user account is the service configured to run as?  *Why* does the service need to reconfigure itself in the first place?  That's a very unusual requirement.

Comment: ... the manifest setting has no effect on a service, by the way.  The service's security context is determined entirely by the service configuration.

Comment: usually `SERVICE_CHANGE_CONFIG`, which need, granted not only to `Administrators` but to `SYSTEM` also. however this depend from concrete service

Comment: >>Why does the service need to reconfigure itself in the first place? That's >>a very unusual requirement.

Comment: The service is protected by SERVICE_LAUNCH_PROTECTED_ANTIMALWARE_LIGHT

Comment: Before uninstalling the service this protection must be removed. There is only one way to remove the protection. "When you uninstall a protected service, the service must mark itself as unprotected by calling the ChangeServiceConfig2 API."

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn313124(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Sorry for dump question but how could I create a service with Administrator privilege?

Comment: I use following to create the service schService = CreateService(
        schSCManager,      
        pszServiceName,   
        pszDisplayName,              
  SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS | SERVICE_CHANGE_CONFIG,           
        SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS,  
        SERVICE_DEMAND_START,               
        SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL,         
        szPath,                     
        NULL,                       
        NULL,                           
        L"",               
        L"NT AUTHORITY\\LocalService",                     
        NULL                    
        );

Answer (score 0):

When creating the service, the `lpServiceStartName` argument determines the security context that the service will run in.

From the [documentation for CreateService](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682450(v=vs.85).aspx):

> If this parameter is NULL, CreateService uses the LocalSystem account.

So in order for your service to run with administrator privilege, you need to specify `NULL` instead of an account name.  According to the comments, you are currently running as Local Service; this does not grant administrator privileges.